# Pubnub V4 Migration Callbacks

Tags: java, android, pubnub

I am trying to update my Code from pubnub sdk v3 to v4 and I am stuck at callbacks.

I have following function which I would like to update:

```
void transmitMessage(String toID, JSONObject packet){
    if (this.id==null){ .
        mRtcListener.onDebug(new PnRTCMessage("Cannot transmit before calling Client.connect"));
    }
    try {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        message.put(PnRTCMessage.JSON_PACKET, packet);
        message.put(PnRTCMessage.JSON_ID, ""); 
        message.put(PnRTCMessage.JSON_NUMBER, this.id);
        this.mPubNub.publish(toID, message, new Callback() {                   
            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message, String timetoken) {
                mRtcListener.onDebug(new PnRTCMessage((JSONObject)message));
            }

            @Override
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubNubError error) {
                mRtcListener.onDebug(new PnRTCMessage(error.errorObject));
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The docs say one does not Need to instantiate com.pubnub.api.Callback and one should use the new `SubscribeCallback` class. I am not sure how to handle it, the `SubscribeCallback` contains These Methods: Status, message and presence, currently I have a `successCallback` method and a `errorCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

The code at https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#listeners should help you with this.

You can create listeners using the code below:

```
pubnub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
@Override
public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
    switch (status.getOperation()) {
        // let's combine unsubscribe and subscribe handling for ease of use
        case PNSubscribeOperation:
        case PNUnsubscribeOperation:
            // note: subscribe statuses never have traditional
            // errors, they just have categories to represent the
            // different issues or successes that occur as part of subscribe
            switch (status.getCategory()) {
                case PNConnectedCategory:
                    // this is expected for a subscribe, this means there is no error or issue whatsoever
                case PNReconnectedCategory:
                    // this usually occurs if subscribe temporarily fails but reconnects. This means
                    // there was an error but there is no longer any issue
                case PNDisconnectedCategory:
                    // this is the expected category for an unsubscribe. This means there
                    // was no error in unsubscribing from everything
                case PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
                    // this is usually an issue with the internet connection, this is an error, handle appropriately
                case PNAccessDeniedCategory:
                    // this means that PAM does allow this client to subscribe to this
                    // channel and channel group configuration. This is another explicit error
                default:
                    // More errors can be directly specified by creating explicit cases for other
                    // error categories of `PNStatusCategory` such as `PNTimeoutCategory` or `PNMalformedFilterExpressionCategory` or `PNDecryptionErrorCategory`
            }

        case PNHeartbeatOperation:
            // heartbeat operations can in fact have errors, so it is important to check first for an error.
            // For more information on how to configure heartbeat notifications through the status
            // PNObjectEventListener callback, consult <link to the PNCONFIGURATION heartbeart config>
            if (status.isError()) {
                // There was an error with the heartbeat operation, handle here
            } else {
                // heartbeat operation was successful
            }
        default: {
            // Encountered unknown status type
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
    String messagePublisher = message.getPublisher();
    System.out.println("Message publisher: " + messagePublisher);
    System.out.println("Message Payload: " + message.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Message Subscription: " + message.getSubscription());
    System.out.println("Message Channel: " + message.getChannel());
    System.out.println("Message timetoken: " + message.getTimetoken());
}

@Override
public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {

}
```

});

Once you've subscribed to a channel like below, when a message or presence event is received the above listeners will be called.

```
pubnub.subscribe()
.channels(Arrays.asList("my_channel")) // subscribe to channels
.withPresence() // also subscribe to related presence information
.execute();
```

Please note that we have recently launched new features with new types of listeners as well, all of which are listed in the link above.

Comment: @hunjm - What Paras has provided is correct. What I think you may be challenged with is that we moved the callback from being in every `subscribe` call that you make to a centralized listener. This may require you to refactor your `callback` handling code for receiving a message, connection success/failure and presence events from the "per subscribe" model to this central listener model. Mainly just just need to move that code and perhaps check the channel name if you need to handle it differently per channel.

Comment: If you have further challenges, feel free to open a support ticket with [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and we can provide further guidance.